# Tailwind align sidemenu centre vertical

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I have a simple aside in tailwind like this

```
<aside class="hidden lg:block h-screen">
    <div>
        <div class="w-20 bg-white pt-2 rounded-2xl flex flex-col justify-center h-4/5 m-auto">
            <ul class="flex flex-col items-center">
                <li>
                    1
                </li>
                <li>
                    1
                </li>
                <li>
                    1
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

It's showing like this. I need to show that white box it in centre vertically

[image]

Comment: Ummm... it _is_ in the center.  Do want it in a row?  Just drop the `flex-col`.

Comment: @jmargolisvt need to centre vertically

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example using tailwind play? https://play.tailwindcss.com/ Copying your code seems okay, and it isn't easy to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your code and display is not matching , you are producing different output for the code !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<aside class="hidden lg:block h-screen">
    <div class="flex h-screen justify-center items-center">
        <div class="w-20 bg-white pt-2 rounded-2xl flex flex-col justify-center h-4/5 m-auto">
            <ul class="flex flex-col items-center">
                <li>
                    1
                </li>
                <li>
                    1
                </li>
                <li>
                    1
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code and the output doesn't match. I have tried to reproduce code according to the question, hope it helps.

```
<aside class="hidden h-screen md:block">
  <div class="flex h-screen items-start bg-blue-100">
    <div class="m-auto flex w-20 flex-col justify-center rounded-2xl bg-white pt-2">
      <ul class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

[image]